# Jupyter Notebook KernelRestarter restarts and then Notebook Killed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

On a linux machine I had a Jupyter Notebook running for hours.

When I returned, in the browser I saw this:
[image]

Thus, I went to the terminal where I had launched the Notebook and I saw:

```
[I 20:23:40.243 NotebookApp] Saving file at /somedir/notebook.ipynb
[I 20:24:24.754 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 860905d3-ee34-4e22-8c9d-e8faecec1f5c restarted
[I 20:24:32.415 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 9ebb0a05-9328-4506-b5e2-df7789e57857 restarted
[I 20:25:05.478 NotebookApp] Saving file at /somedir/notebook.ipynb
[I 20:25:40.632 NotebookApp] Saving file at /somedir/notebook.ipynb
Killed
(condaEnvName) hostname:username$ [IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
```

Any idea what happened?

What caused (or could have caused) the KernelRestarter to kickoff?

What is the `Killed` line and is it related to the KernelRestarter?

Who is the "Parent" which "appears to have excited"?

Answer (score 3):

It is caused by opening too many files in new tab and trying to close these files with only closing browser tabs. To close a file which is opened in a new tab, click "File" -> "Close and Halt". This closes the file in a proper way, the file cannot run in background and cause to this error.